# Is there any google analytics reporting ruby gem available to get most popular products from e-commerce section ?

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, rubygems, google-analytics-api

I am looking for a solution where I can fetch google analytics data like Popular Products, traffic on Mobile device, Avg Cart value etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Ruby Google API client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/), which is designed to call the [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). The reporting API is capable of querying any of populated [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). The hardest part will be setting up [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth) but after that it is all down hill. If you get stuck setting up OAuth feel free to come back to SO to ask any problems you are having with your code.